# Article content overview field

Tags: knowledge, articles, object

I am trying to write a query to retrieve the title, document description and content overview of an article. I am able to find the title and document description on object KnowledgeArticleVersion. But not sure where the content overview field/object is.

If this is on another object, what is the relationship of that object with KnowledgeArticleVersion objec?

Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can you verify the answer and send your comments

Answer (score 2):

I think Content Overview is the custom field. You can verify this field & related API in article types (Object API Name ends with _kav). You can retrieve the field values using SOQL query.